# Admin of my app but still can't test action

Tags: facebook, action

I am an admin of my app. I am trying to test an action in the graph API explorer and comes back with....

```
 {
   "error": {
   "message": "(#100) The Action Type namespace:Place is not approved, so app 1456349955xxxxx can only publish to administrators, developers, and testers of the app.  User 63114xxxx is not one of those roles.", 
   "type": "OAuthException", 
   "code": 100
   }
 }
```

The user id is actually my user id. Anyone else struck this?

Comment: have you selected the app for which you are admin. Why I am asking is, by default, it uses graph api explorer app.

Comment: Yep, you were right I changed that just after I posted the question. I get a action instance id now, nothing turns up on my time line tho.

Comment: in timeline, you should check in activity or check in RECENT APPS

Comment: If I preview manually i.e `https://www.facebook.com/dhirenp/activity/10100657260775943` I can see the post

Comment: you can see it activity log also. And in timeline, there will be an aggregation box called activity you can find there  also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should select the app for which you are admin. By default, it uses graph api explorer app.

You can find the app in timeline
[image]